# iPhone Simulator in Xcode6 sends OS version of my Mac

Tags: ios, ios8, xcode6, simulator

While investigating why I'm not getting ads from ad-networks, I stumbled upon a weird issue, the WebView's User-Agent:

`User Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_10 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1 Mobile/9A334 Safari/7534.48.3`

Whereas since I'm running for iOS8, it rather should be:

`User Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 8_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1 Mobile/9A334 Safari/7534.48.3`

Ofcourse there's no iPhone running version 10.10 as yet, so Xcode6 is somehow picking up version from Mac OS X. For iOS 7.1 simulators, it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

That's always been the case as I far as I know.

When I use the following code to determine what OS I am running on, and what hardware, it's always returned the OSX host information, and not the simulated iOS information:

```
NSString *systemVersion = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
...
sysctlbyname("kern.version", buffer, &len, NULL, 0);
...
sysctlbyname("hw.model", buffer, &len, NULL, 0);
```

WebKit is obviously using similar techniques when filling out its client browser information.  It shouldn't cause an issue, however.

Comment: Interesting..
On iOS 7 & below, the value logged is the same(expected), however on iOS8, I see that systemVersion logs as 8.0, whereas WebKit still appends 10_10 in the User Agent String.
Wondering if this is a bug in WebKit with OS 8.0?